# Does Facebook's personal ranking algorithm leak external profile data?

Tags: facebook, algorithm, facebook-graph-api

I recently came across [this script](http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2013/11/10/script-shows-facebook-ranks-friends/) that extracts friend rank data from the currently logged-in Facebook profile and presents it as a table.

After trying the script personally, I became puzzled as to why certain individuals were consistently ranked higher than others. The rank seems to refresh daily, so I have experimented with various user interaction, and this shifts many entries appropriately; however, the same 'certain individual(s)' would often (with no discernible interaction) arbitrarily move up in rank.

My question is this: ***is it possible that this rank is being affected by other, external profile's usage data/habits?***

In the interests of privacy, it seems very unlikely that anything but personal habits would influence this ranking, but my own and other peoples' usage anecdotes seem to suggest 'arbitrary' movement that would only be explained by external data.

I cannot seem to find a definitive answer to this elsewhere.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Your statement "In the interests of privacy..." strikes me as counter-intuitive, especially in regards to facebook. If two people have similar habits/likes, they *should* be ranked higher to each other, right? If another person's usage/habits *didn't* affect it, what would be the point? Also, on a tangent, when did facebook start caring about privacy?

Comment: It is already known Facebook is selling user data to 3rd parties. They really don't care about privacy that much. You can check news sites, they have lots of articles on this.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on 'machine learning'. What you and your friends look at and 'like' are the key drivers to the ranking. However, the algorithms in use are constantly re-evaluating the appropriate weightings to be used. For example if one of your friends clicks 'like' on two items, and you click 'like' on one of them, the algo needs to determine whether those facts are significant. Part of that determination will come from analysis of who else has 'liked' those items, what else they have liked, and whether those actions are likely to imply other similar tastes.